# Assigning variables confusion in Python 3

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I thought I understood how assignment works, but after running these two pieces of code I realized I am pretty confused now.

This is in Python 3.3:

```
numbers=[1,4,3]
hello=numbers.reverse()
print(hello)
None
```

When I `print(numbers)` instead, I get `[3,4,1]` which is what I was expecting when printing `hello`.

On another example:

```
numbers='yeah'
hello=numbers.capitalize()
print(hello)
Yeah
```

How come when assigning a list to second variable, like the first example shows, I get None when printing that second variable, but when assigning a string this does not happen? I ran it in the Python visualizer, but this still does not answer my question as to how/why this is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `numbers.reverse()` reverses the list **in place**.

Your code shoud be:

```
numbers=[1,4,3]
numbers.reverse()
print(numbers)
```

or if you don't want to modify original list `numbers`, copy numbers to hello:

```
from copy import copy
numbers=[1,4,3]
hello=copy(numbers)
hello.reverse()
print(hello)
```

The documentation of the methods will always tell you if the method works **in place** (i.e. it change the object you are calling the method on to), or if it **returns** the result

Answer (score 1):

As in document specified, [`list.reverse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) "reverse the elements of the list in place" while [`str.capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) "return a copy of word with only its first character capitalized."

One works in-place while the other returns the result.